# DateTime2 value not getting converted to Datetime using At Time Zone SQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone-offset

I am writing function to use At Time Zone SQL function to convert timestamp to local timestamp based on timezone value.

The source timestamp column has datetime2 datatype and a  `value=2020-10-29 23:59:59.997000`.

When I am trying to convert it to datetime using

```
CAST(CAST(Timestamp AS DatetimeOffset) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS DATETIME)
```

I am getting `value=2020-10-29 23:59:59.996667` which is incorrect.

What to be added so value is in datetime.

Comment: I don't get your result https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4bdec5d7a5419121be603a21b86230d please create a [mcve]

Comment: I don't get your result either.  I get `2020-10-29 16:59:59.997` as well on my local 2019 instance.

Comment: I made a guess but it would be helpful if you also describe what output you _expect_ and why. Saying only that what you're getting is incorrect is only part of the story.

Comment: I am expecting  output in datettime format:2020-10-29 23:59:59.997

Comment: But where are you "getting" `2020-10-29 23:59:59.996667`? I don't see that output in db<>fiddle or in Management Studio. Casting the entire result to datetime should make 6 decimal places completely impossible. Can you please post a full repro to db<>fiddle instead of just telling us what you're getting?

Comment: i have field in my table endtimestamp. i am converting to localendtimestamp using:  cast(cast(EndTimestamp as datetimeoffset) At Time Zone 'GMT Standard Time' as datetime) but im getting output as 2020-10-29 23:59:59.996667:

Comment: Maybe show your whole query / statement?  Somewhere you're returning a DATETIME2 instead of DATETIME, or maybe you're not actually updating a column somewhere, or something...

Comment: Saying you have a field somewhere is very hand-wavy. Go to [db<>fiddle](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle), build a table, populate it with sample data, and show the _exact_ query you're running that's giving you the wrong results. We can't fix "I have a field somewhere" and "I'm getting output <somewhere?>"...

Comment: @user2431858 - what are you trying to accomplish? Is your source data a `datetime2` in terms of UTC and you're wanting to convert it to Pacific time?  Or is your source data in terms of Pacific time and you want to convert it to UTC?  (In neither case is `'GMT Standard Time'` correct - that's the local time for Great Britain (GMT/BST).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I may have discovered your issue. When you take your DATETIME2, cast it to DATETIME, then back to DATETIME2(6), you get your result:

### Query to Demonstrate Your Issue

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2020-10-29 23:59:59.997' AS DATETIME) AS DATETIME2(6))

--Returns 2020-10-29 23:59:59.996667
```

It's hard to ascertain what you need, but it looks like you are trying to grab the local time in the same datatype DATETIME2(6) as your original data. `AT TIME ZONE` returns DATETIMEOFFSET, so just need to convert back to DATETIME after (assuming your original data is in UTC time). See below query

### Return Local Time without Offset Info

```
DECLARE @d2 DATETIME2(6) = '2020-10-29 23:59:59.997000'

SELECT CAST(@d2 AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed description but i am looking converting datettime 2 original value to datettime .

Comment: Adjusted second query to output DATETIME

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint thanks, I forgot to mark it as UTC before converting to PST. Corrected the second query

Comment: Thanks all for taking out time and sending out comments